# CC1310 TI Launchpad: PWM output on DIO pin no output signal

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, telecommunication

We're trying to output a PWM signal along the dio23 analog pin. We set the CC1310_LAUNCHXL_PWMPIN0 to IOID_23 and ran the code below; however, when viewed on oscilloscope directly from the pin no output signal is detected. Is there anything we're missing?

```
    PWM_Handle handle;
    PWM_Params params;
    /* Call driver init functions. */
    PWM_init();

    PWM_Params_init(&params);
    params.idleLevel = PWM_IDLE_LOW;
    params.periodUnits = PWM_PERIOD_HZ;
    params.periodValue = 1e6;
    params.dutyUnits = PWM_DUTY_FRACTION;
    params.dutyValue = 100;

    handle = PWM_open(Board_PWM0, &params);
    if(handle==NULL){
        while(1);
    }
    PWM_start(handle);
    while(1);
```

Comment: Did you switch on power supply for GPIO? GPIO peripheral needs to be powered usually in Cortex M architecture

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually You have set too small duty. 100 is not 100%, but 100/PWM_DUTY_FRACTION_MAX, where PWM_DUTY_FRACTION_MAX is 2^32-1 - see documentation: http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/tirtos/2_20_00_06/exports/tirtos_full_2_20_00_06/products/tidrivers_msp43x_2_20_00_08/docs/doxygen/html/_p_w_m_8h.html

Try setting dutyValue to PWM_DUTY_FRACTION_MAX/2 (or other big value) and You should see result.